# Using PHP to check if each word in a string is a minimum number of characters?

Tags: php

Is there any simple way with PHP to verify that each word in a string is at least 5 characters?

I've looked into `strlen` and `str_word_count` but haven't found anything that I can use to say "if each word is N length, do this".  Each word is separated by a space.

Comment: @Shlomtzion No, it's not.  That's getting the length of an entire string.  Not verifying the length of each individual word in a string.

Comment: Split the string, then loop the resulting array and check the length of each item in it

Comment: Note also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php is `number of bytes rather than the number of characters`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php would be for number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode your string into an array, map each word to its length, call `min()` on the result.

```php
function shortest_word_length($s)
{
    return min(array_map(function($word) { return strlen($word); }, explode(' ', $s)));
}
$s = 'this is a string';
echo shortest_word_length($s); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to split your string to words then do that:

```
$str = "Hello all developers";

$arrayStr = explode(' ',$str);
// example we need to pass the first word
function checkWord($word,$max = 5) {
   return strlen($word) < 5;
}
//example we pass first word `Hello`
if (checkWord($arrayStr[0])) {
   echo "yes, it is less than 5";
} else {
   echo "sorry";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is formed from the string with `explode()`.
The minimum word length is delivered directly with [array_reduce()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and a special user function.

```
$str = "Hello all friends of PHP";
$minWordLen = array_reduce(
  explode(" ",$str), 
  function($carry, $item){ 
    return ($len = strlen($item)) < $carry ? $len : $carry; 
  }, 
  PHP_INT_MAX)
;
// 2
```